# General real solution of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Learning for an extra resit of a university exam I was trying to find my mistakes in the resit. However, I can't come to the given solution for the following question(the 4th answer is mine and the 3rd should be correct):

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDgGt.png)
When I calculated it myself with the following calculations, I calculated the eigenvalues to be $5+3i$ and $5-3i$

[Calculation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sapnB.png)
Then using the following calculations I determined the  corresponding eigenvectors to be $[1+3i;5]$ and $[1-3i;5]$.

[Calculation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMn7.png)
I verified this using Matlab and some websites such as Symbolab.

Then I used the following calculations to come to my final answer:

[Calculation 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVDZl.png)
This option is not given in the list of possible answers. The values for the last answer correspond to my findings but do not qualify due to the missing $3$ in front of the t's in the (co)sines. Can anybody find my mistake(s) and help me come to the final answer?

The teacher says she will not share the calculations and that the eigenvector should probably be multiplied with a (complex)constant first but I cannot find which.

Comment: Even if you do not reproduce the full page structure of the test, at least reproduce the main steps in mathjax so that one can understand the question without loading the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your calculations do not contain an error. However, the checked answer "None of the other answers are correct" is wrong, as the third variant is indeed correct. At the stage
$$
A-\lambda I=\pmatrix{1-3i&-2\\5&-1-3i}
$$
you decided on forming the kernel vector from the components of the second row and got $\pmatrix{1+3i\\5}$. You could the same way form it from the first row to find that the kernel is also generated by $\pmatrix{2\\1-3i}$ which then using the same procedures for the remaining steps gives the third answer variant. You get indeed the first kernel vector from the second by multiplication with the complex scalar $\dfrac{1+3i}2$.